# MQTT Broker username/password exposed in client/browser side configuration

Tags: frontend, mqtt, publish-subscribe, distributed-system, mqtt-vernemq

I'm currently using VerneMQ as our MQTT pub/sub message broker. In our front-end side, we are using the paho-mqtt npm to connect to the broker and subscribe to topics. Data is pushed through topics by our backend services. The purpose of the UI is just to consume data through the topics.

However, in our client side configuration we are exposing our broker credentials in a way that it can be visible in the network console if someone really tried to look for it. Is there any way I can extract this away or use a more secure authentication process? If I do not provide the username/password, it cannot establish successful web socket connection.

```
this.mqtt.connect({
        useSSL: this.mqttUseSSL,
        userName: this.mqttUser, //username exposed here
        password: this.mqttPwd, //password exposed here
        onSuccess: () => this.onConnect(),
        onFailure: (err) => this.onFailure(err)
      });
```

Comment: The most obvious solution would be to have the users connect to the broker with a username and password that is unique to them. VerneMQ supports [authentication using a database](https://docs.vernemq.com/configuration/db-auth) so there's nothing stopping you from writing unique credentials to the database and serving them to the front-end for the mqtt client connection.

Comment: thanks! I will take a look at this

Answer (score -1):

I have the same doubt. I find it very insecure to expose them. As an alternative solution, it would be to use SocketIo making a kind of proxy to the frontend with the WS protocol.